# int or char? which is faster?

Tags: c, performance

My C program stores many integer values in memory and reads them and performs comparisons on them frequently. The range of the type `unsigned char` is adequate, but I have used `int` because speed is much more important than memory consumption to me and I thought maybe CPU works with `int`s faster. But it was just a crude intuitional guess and I'm far from being sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the constraints,  you should probably be using `uint_fast8_t` which gives you what is generally the fastest unsigned type that is capable of storing at least `uint8_t` values (where `uint8_t` is usually `unsigned char`, of course).  The type is defined in [`<stdint.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.3) in C99 and later (and `uint_fast8_t` is required to be defined, but it is not necessarily the same as `uint8_t`, and `uint8_t` need not be defined if the CPU does not support 8-bit bytes).

If you go down this route, you'll probably need to brush up on the correct format specifiers for the `printf()` and `scanf()` families of functions.  These are defined in [`<inttypes.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1).  Using anything else is fraught with portability issues (at least in theory).

Comment: Thanks. But in what sense are these integer types the fastest? In arithmetic? In read time from cache? Both?

Comment: And doesn't type promotion affect speed?

Comment: They are an assessment by the compiler writers that you will get fastest overall integer performance using the type.  Read the material linked the question (under `<stdint.h>`).  Yes, type promotion does affect speed; that may be why the `uint_fast8_t` type is actually a 32-bit unsigned integer type — rather than a 16-bit unsigned type or an 8-bit unsigned type.  You have to think about masking the  type, too — although `uint_fast8_t` can hold an unsigned 8-bit integer value, it may be able to hold bigger numbers, so addition such as `128 + 128` will store `256` rather than `0`.

Comment: I note that using `int` also requires masking — it's unlikely that `uint_fast8_t` is worse than `int`.