# Create new data type in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create a new data type in C++.
I have some variables whose values are never going to be >100. So, I want to create a new datatype to store values only between 0 and 100 which would also take up less memory. I could use
`unsigned short smth = 100;`
but unsigned short also takes up 16 bits and there will be a lot of unused values. Something like the `byte` datatype in java is needed.

16 bits probably won't matter but want to extract all the juice of performance from my application.

If it is not possible in C++ is there any way of doing it in C and implementing in C++ code?

Comment: Try using `int8_t`, it takes 8 bits. which is the minimum you will need to store a number like 100

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Classes can be used for this.

Comment: Maybe you can use [bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field)

Comment: if you want to "extract all the juice of performance" from your application then you shouldn't ever use `unsigned short` unless it's a huge array. [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5069489/995714), [int or char? which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55428554/995714), [When to use `short` over `int`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371077/995714)

Comment: @김선달 bitfields are even worse for performance because you'll need many more instructions to extract and set the values. It's only reasonable when you have a large array that doesn't fit in cache. In short the question is just a [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/98103) premise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "extract all the juice of performance from your application", you should not use other datatypes than types that are the size of a register (which may be `int` in your implementation).

If you don't care about portability, I recommend using `uint_fast8_t`.
It is `atleast 8 bits, but the implementation uses the faster type which can be bigger`

The other answers - encapsulating the functionality into a class, are also valid and should be combined with my advice.

Answer (score 1):

For the storage, you can use `(unsigned) char`, or better `(u)int8_t`.  Or even `std::byte` in C++17 and later.

And then you can wrap that inside a `class` or `struct` that restricts the values that can be assigned to it.

Comment: `std::byte` is not meant for arithmetic, but indeed just "a collection of bits", hence why it does not allow any arithmetic on them and is therefore unsuited for storing a number.